# Issue in installing AWS EB CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following [this instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-windows.html) to install eb cli, but it raise this error:

```
Will not install to the user site because it will lack sys.path precedence to python-dateutil in c:\virtual envs\python_XXXX\lib\site-packages
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-windows.html

I basically run this pip command:

```
pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user
```

On Python 3.8 in a virtual env

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @hephalump Shoot! forgot the error message, added. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing within a virtual environment, run the same command, but without --user. Refer to this issue here https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/573

Comment: While it is alright to post a link as an answer. Link-only answers are not encouraged. Links have a chance of going invalid in the future. So consider editing your answer and add the relevant part from the link in you post.

Comment: I get this error without using --user.